# is there a method to filter dict in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

i tried this function in javascript :

```
var words = $('textarea#id_keywords').val();
$('#rangeVal').change(function(){
  console.log(this.value);

  console.log(words);
  $('input#id_wordcloud3_keywords').val('toto');
  $('input#id_wordcloud3_keywords').trigger('change');
});
```

with var words contains :

```
 {'type': 'new', 'entity': [], 'w': [{'text': 'balabala', 'relevance': 1, 'index': 0.0010035}, {'text': 'numéro', 'relevance': 1, 'index': 0.14269}, {'text': 'majeur', 'relevance': 1, 'index': 0.0886}]}
```

so i tried to sort the array according to index :

```
var words = $('textarea#id_keywords').val();
$('#rangeVal').change(function(){
  console.log(this.value);
  //console.log(words);

  var tableauObjets = words['w'];
  var result = tableauObjets.filter(x => x['index'] <= this.value);

  console.log(result);
  
});
```

but i have an error:

```
 uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>
```

Comment: i think that the problem in  "var words = $('textarea#id_keywords').val();" 
we cannot use this in " var tableauObjets = words['w'] " like this .... i am beginner in javascript ...

Comment: words is a string.... unclear why you are using bracket notation with it. I assume you want to take the value inside of the input and convert it into an actual object.

Comment: yes exactly, how we can do this ?

Comment: Well the fact it is not valid JSON means you would have to use eval

Comment: i dot understand; can tou show me an example how we can do this, im beginner on javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Comment: i tried JSON.parse(words) but i have a problem because in words the keys are between single quotes not double quotes , how we can change the encode of quotes to double quotes ?